# MariaDB Galera Cluster hang after issue cluster command

Tags: linux, redhat, database, cluster, mariadb

When trying to cluster two MariaDB Galera servers on RHEL 6 together using the command:

```
mysqld -uroot --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
```

and the screen then sits there, and looks at me with this output:

```
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130805 10:26:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130805 10:26:50  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130805 10:26:51 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-29.3 started; log sequence number 5715012
130805 10:26:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
130805 10:26:51 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130805 10:26:51 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
130805 10:26:51 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
130805 10:26:51 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.29-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.3.rXXXX
```

As far as I can tell, it seems to be working. I then issued the command to connect to this cluster master:

```
$ mysqld -uroot --wsrep_cluster_address=gcom://mariadbclstr02.local.net

130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130805 11:27:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130805 11:27:21  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130805 11:27:22 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-29.3 started; log sequence number 1598129
130805 11:27:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
130805 11:27:22 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130805 11:27:22 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
130805 11:27:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
130805 11:27:22 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.29-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.3.rXXXX
```

Now they're both just sitting there, and nothing is happening as far as I can tell. Is there a way to see if they are doing this correctly? I'm following the documentation at the MariaDB website: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/. I can also use netcat to connect to both servers using `nc -vz mariadbclstr02.local.net 3306` and also `nc -vz mariadbclstr01.local.net 3306`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I discovered, instead of issuing the commands like I did, I had to edit the `/etc/my.cnf` and add those lines. Instead thought, I created a `/etc/my.cnf.d/zabbix_cluster.cnf` file and put the lines specified at https://kb.askmonty.org/en/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/. Then I was able to start MySQL properly. Then after editing the `/etc/my.cnf/zabbix_cluster.cnf` config file, I had to start the cluster up by issuing `/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://` which would then initialize a new cluster and allow others to join.